# select first two division from three div's which are present in a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to display first two fields i.e garage_quoted_amt and quoted_amt from given division , so please help me out. i'm newbie in jquery.
    i have used this condition to show below condition

```
$("#priceDifference div.row:not(:nth-of-type(3))").show();
```

please direct me in correct way.

```
<div class="row" id="priceDifference" style="display:none;">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-1 col-lg-offset-1 form-group">
              <label style="padding-top:5px;">&nbsp;Quoted Price</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" name="quoted_amt" id="gobumpr_quoted_amt<?php echo $booking_id; ?>" class="form-control" style="max-width:280px;"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-1 col-lg-offset-1 form-group">
              <label style="padding-top:5px;">&nbsp;Garage Quoted Price</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" name="garage_quoted_amt" id="garage_quoted_amt<?php echo $booking_id; ?>" class="form-control" style="max-width:280px;"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-1 col-lg-offset-1 form-group">
              <label style="padding-top:5px;">&nbsp;Local Garage Quote</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" name="local_garage_quoted_amt" id="local_garage_quoted_amt<?php echo $booking_id; ?>" class="form-control" style="max-width:280px;"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The thing is i need to display all the three fields that is  local_garage_quoted_amt too after displaying two fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Remove `style="display:none;"` from parent div `<div class="row" id="priceDifference">`

2.use [:gt() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

```
$("#priceDifference div.gt(1)").hide();
```

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#priceDifference .row:gt(1)").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="priceDifference"><!-- remove style="display:none;"-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-1 col-lg-offset-1 form-group">
      <label style="padding-top:5px;">&nbsp;GoBumpr Quoted Price</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" name="quoted_amt" id="gobumpr_quoted_amt<?php echo $booking_id; ?>" class="form-control" style="max-width:280px;"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-1 col-lg-offset-1 form-group">
      <label style="padding-top:5px;">&nbsp;Garage Quoted Price</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" name="garage_quoted_amt" id="garage_quoted_amt<?php echo $booking_id; ?>" class="form-control" style="max-width:280px;"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-1 col-lg-offset-1 form-group">
      <label style="padding-top:5px;">&nbsp;Local Garage Quote</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" name="local_garage_quoted_amt" id="local_garage_quoted_amt<?php echo $booking_id; ?>" class="form-control" style="max-width:280px;"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @GopalNaikGuguloth  glad to help you :):)

Comment: when i am selecting same div where i need to display all fields only two files are displayed can you please help me out.

Comment: @GopalNaikGuguloth  `when i am selecting same div`-> what do you mean? div with same `id's`?

Comment: div with priceDifference contains 3 fields. from three we have hidden last one but now i want to display all the three 3 fields for a value in drop-down which i have not mention here.

Comment: The thing is i need to display all the three fields that is  local_garage_quoted_amt too after displaying two fields. @Alive to Die

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show a child of a hidden element. Once an element is hidden, all of it`s childs are hidden. What you can do, is to show the parent container and hide all of it`s childs except the ones you need to be shown.

Maybe add a class of `hidden` on the rows you dont want to display and add that class to your css like `.hidden { display: none; }` or set their style to `display:none` directly in html like you did with the parent `row`.